# Working of this Circuit - Reset

Tags: voltage, current, diodes, ethernet, reset

I'm using [this](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/KSZ9031RNX.pdf) Ethernet transceiver PHY to study the working of the RGMII interface.

Can someone explain the working of figure 18 on page 75?
What is the purpose of D1 and D2 along with the RC?
How does it work?

[image]

Comment: please add figure 18 to your post ... you can also use the schematic editor to draw the circuit ... the button is in the toolbar when you are editing your question ... click "save and insert" to add the schematic to your post

Answer (score 1):

D1 creates a power-on reset (POR) pulse.

D1 discharges capacitor C much more rapidly than resistor R would when power rail DVDDH goes to 0 V.  The idea is that if there is a power bounce, C is almost completely discharged and then charges up through R.  Without D1, the KSZ part might not see a level change and reset itself.

D2 is an OR-ing diode (actually, an AND diode).

From capacitor C's point of view, either D1 or D2 can discharge it by going low.  D2 also prevents the connection to the CPU/FPGA from holding C high during a POR event.  During a POR, D2 is reverse biased.  When the CPU RST output goes low to force the KSZ device to reset, D1 is reverse biased.

Update:

The POR part of this circuit handles one of two possible power-bounce or power-cycle scenarios.  When DVDDH goes away, it can do that by:

a) being disconnected, at which time the D1-R node is floating (not connected to any impedance or voltage/current source).  As DVDDH probably power other circuits, this probably is not the case.

b) going to 0 V relatively quickly, as in the power supply being turned off, and its own output circuit or current through other circuits and/or external loads discharging the supply's output capacitance to 0 V.  This presents a low impedance to GND the D1-R node.

The circuit works for case b.  C is discharged quickly through D1 to 0.5 V, and then more slowly down to 0 V, through whatever external impedance to GND exists.  If that impedance is low (case b), C can be discharged in milliseconds.  If it is high (case a), it might take minutes.  If power is restored before C has discharged below the KSZ device's input transition level, the device will not see a reset condition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please confirm with an example of voltage levels between the two devices during and after POR?

Comment: See update. . . . .

Answer (score 1):

D1 is supposed to discharge C when the power supply rail falls. The input is a type Ipu (internal pullup) with a loosely specified (-40 to -120uA current) input pullup of some kind (all numbers here assuming 3.3V supply). Input low voltage is 1.3V and input high voltage 2.0V. It's not clear if the RESET_N input has Schmitt trigger functionality.

When power is re-applied the voltage at C is supposed to be less than 1.3V (so the supply should have fallen to less than about 0.6V) and then the capacitor charges through the parallel combination of the internal pullup and the external 10K resistor. The time constant of that is around 100ms, so the RESET_N input should be held active low for (very roughly) around that time.

D2 allows an external logic level (it must have a logic high level equal or similar to the  KSZ9031) to reset the KSZ9031 by pulling it low through the diode. The large 10uF capacitor will affect the external logic level transition, probably slowing it to 1ms-ish fall time, depending on the drive capability of the external logic.

This is altogether a very "cheap and nasty" reset arrangement unsuited for high reliability applications. You need a  proper reset circuit with precise voltage thresholds, guaranteed to assert a valid level down to very low supply voltage, and controlled minimum pulse width to get a reliable reset. This will work okay if the power is always 'off' for a  "long" time (depending on the external loads on the power supply to get it down to <0.6V) and if the power is switched cleanly every time. To put it bluntly, this kind of garbage circuit is responsible for much consumer frustration such as having to cycle power on routers during electrical storms.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please confirm with an example of voltage levels between the two devices during and after POR?

Comment: If the power rail has gone right down to 0V  (say the power has been off for an hour) then the capacitor will start from ~0V and charge upward towards 3.3V. If the CPU drives the reset the voltage will start from about 0.7V and charge upwards towards 3.3V.